# Why do I need to change random modifier to be Static?

Tags: java, class, random

I am teaching myself Java and was creating a simple game.  I got the whole thing working which is awesome.. I've learned a ton along the way.  I decided to split out my code into separate classes so I can learn a little more, clean up the cose, and also not have to repeat code!

In my main method I have an instance of random such as

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

this worked just fine when calling

```
dragonMoves[rand.nextInt(5)]
```

in my main method.

Once I moved that code to a new class, it required me to change

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

to be static.  This fixes all errors, but I just am looking to understand why it might do that?  If I can provide more information to be more helpful, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: In the other class, are you trying to use `rand` from a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what a static context is. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129706/java-static-context) and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

Might you are using that `instance` member in a  `static` context.

You cannot use a non `static` member instance in a static context. That is what compiler is complaining.

Either you need to create a new `instance` with in that static context or member should be `static`.

Reason is that static methods or members are attached to class rather than a `instance`.

Reason is that you can call static method without an instance, so `instance` members should not be used inside that context.

I'm recommending this tutorial of oracle about [`Understanding Instance and Class Members`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)